# One File to Move at a time

Tags: python

i am trying to move one file at a time form one folder to another folder.my python has limitations and not allowing to use all Libraries and i tried using the create date and its working fine but problem is when i have more then 1 file with same create data.
plz help me in this to move only 1 file (it may be any file) at a time each time script execute

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import shutil
import re
import glob

src_dir = "//Server_path/SrcFiles/"
dst_dir = "//Tgt_Path/SrcFiles/"
fn_arg = 'CIP'

src_files = src_dir + '*' + fn_arg + '*'
print(src_files)
files = glob.glob(src_files)
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)
print(files)
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print(latest_file)
a,b= latest_file.rsplit('\\', 1)
print(b)
src = src_dir + b;
tgt = dst_dir + b;
shutil.move(src, tgt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest modified file you can simply get the `files[0]` from the sorted list. Or instead of sorting it this is enough:

```py
files = glob.glob(src_files)
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

If they have the same value of `getmtime` it will still just select one.

There is no way to get the date of creation through python since it is not stored in most filesystems. However you can try using `getctime` which is the date of last metadata changes, and therefore if you change permissions the value will also change.

Comment: Yes i tried with he same but it is moving all 1053 files in single run.

Comment: Its working now.. after removing the sort